# after joining two dataframes pick all columns from one dataframe on basis of primary key

Tags: pyspark

I've two dataframes, I need to update records in df1 based on new updates available in df2 in pyspark.

DF1:

```
df1=spark.createDataFrame([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],["id","val1"])

+---+----+
| id|val1|
+---+----+
|  1|   2|
|  2|   3|
|  3|   4|
+---+----+
```

DF2:

```
df2=spark.createDataFrame([(1,4),(2,5)],["id","val1"])

+---+----+
| id|val1|
+---+----+
|  1|   4|
|  2|   5|
+---+----+
```

then, I'm trying to join the two dataframes.

```
join_con=(df1["id"] == df2["id"])
jdf=df1.join(df2,join_con,"left")

+---+----+----+----+
| id|val1|  id|val1|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|   2|   1|   4|
|  3|   4|null|null|
|  2|   3|   2|   5|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Now, I want to pick all columns from df2 if df2["id"] is not null, otherwise pick all columns of df1.

something like:

```
jdf.filter(df2.id is null).select(df1["*"])
union
jdf.filter(df2.id is not null).select(df2["*"])
```

so resultant DF can be:

```
+---+----+
| id|val1|
+---+----+
|  1|   4|
|  2|   5|
|  3|   4|
+---+----+
```

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: What happens when `df2["id"]` is not null but the `val1` is null, which value will it contain then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selection expression can be a `coalesce` between the column in `df2` followed by `df1`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1=spark.createDataFrame([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4), (4, 1),],["id","val1"])
df2=spark.createDataFrame([(1,4),(2,5), (4, None),],["id","val1"])

selection_expr = [F.when(df2["id"].isNotNull(), df2[c]).otherwise(df1[c]).alias(c) for c in df2.columns]

jdf.select(selection_expr).show()

"""
+---+----+
| id|val1|
+---+----+
|  1|   4|
|  2|   5|
|  3|   4|
|  4|null|
+---+----+
"""
```

Comment: But we need to pick all columns from df2 if df2.id column is not null. so, df2.val1 can be null and we have to pick it(instead of df1.val1) if df2.id is not null.

Comment: @kuldeepmishra modified the answer for cases when df2 columns can contain `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `coalesce` function as this function gets first non null values.

```
expr=zip(df2.columns,df1.columns) 
e1=[coalesce(df2[f[0]],df1[f[1]]).alias(f[0]) for f in expr]
jdf.select(*e1).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|val1|
#+---+----+
#|  1|   4|
#|  2|   5|
#|  3|   4|
#+---+----+
```

Comment: But we need to pick all columns from df2 if df2.id column is not null. so, df2.val1 can be null and we have to pick it(instead of df1.val1) if df2.id is not null.